# javascript if text box element is blank do different action

Tags: javascript, forms, search, if-statement, textbox

Trying to get this search form to do different searches but if the search box is empty, I want it to default to a different page. This is with the first else if. Even with the text box empty it keeps defaulting to the first action.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeAction() {   
      if(document.getElementById('searchOption').value == "title" && document.getElementById('searchText').value!=null) {
       document.getElementById('searchForm').action = 'catalog.com=0&term=' + escape(document.getElementById('searchText').value);
      }
      **else if(document.getElementById('searchOption').value == "title" && document.getElementById('searchText').value===null) {
       document.action = 'differentPage.com'
      }**
      else if(document.getElementById('searchOption').value == "keyword") {
        document.getElementById('searchForm').action = 'catalog.com?keyword=' + escape(document.getElementById('searchText').value);
      }
  else{
       document.getElementById('searchForm').action = "mysite.com/searchResults.html";
       $('#searchForm').attr('method', 'get');
       $('#searchText').attr('name', 'q');
       }
 }
</script>

<form id="searchForm" name=search method=post>
    <div class="subscribe">
        <div class="text">
            <input name="term" type="text" id="searchText"/>
        </div>
        <select id="searchOption" name="searchOption" title="search">
            <option name="index" value="title" selected="selected">TITLE IN CATALOG</option>
            <option name="index" value="keyword" type="hidden">CATALOG KEYWORD</option>
            <option name="nothing" value="googleSearch" type="hidden">LIBRARY WEBSITE</option>
        </select>
        <!-- for google search appliance -->
        <input value="slco_pub" name="client" type="hidden">
        <input value="slco_pub" name="proxystylesheet" type="hidden">
        <input value="xml_no_dtd" name="output" type="hidden">
        <input value="mainSite" name="site" type="hidden">
        <!-- end of necessary for google search appliance -->
        <!-- for ILS -->
        <INPUT name=menu value=search type=hidden>
        <INPUT name=aspect value=basic_search type=hidden>
        <INPUT name=profile value=maincentral type=hidden>
        <!-- Left from old <INPUT name=index value=".TW" type=hidden> -->
        <INPUT name=index value="PALLTI" type=hidden>
        <!-- end of necessary for google search appliance-->
    <!--Button Graphic-->
        <input type="image" src="/sebin/m/p/btn-search.gif" alt="search button" onClick="changeAction();" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to check if it's Null? Null and empty are two different things. An empty string still isn't Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('searchText').value!=null` is using loose comparison, so it will be true if the value is `null` or `undefined`. In this case, it will always be a string. What you want to test is whether it is a non-empty string, like so:

```
var option = document.getElementById('searchOption').value,
    text = document.getElementById('searchText').value,
    form = document.getElementById('searchForm');

if (option === "title" && text.length > 0) {
    form.action = 'catalog.com=0&term=' + escape(text);
}
else if (option === "title" && text.length === 0) {
    form.action = 'differentPage.com'
}
else if (option === "keyword") {
    form.action = 'catalog.com?keyword=' + escape(text);
}
else {
    form.action = "mysite.com/searchResults.html";
    $('#searchForm').attr('method', 'get');
    $('#searchText').attr('name', 'q');
}
```

Note that I've used strict comparison.

Comment: That was what I was going for! Thanks for help.